# Help me understand electrical fields better

Tags: field

I have a hypothetical scenario that would help me better understand (I hope) electrical fields and propagation of electrical fields better.

So let's have a super simple circuit with one voltage source and one resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEcj5d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I understand that Ohms law says that I=U/R so using that we would see 50mA flowing through the whole circuit.

Now I have the hypothetical scenario: lets make this circuit veeeeery large.

Large so that the wires would be 10 times the length that speed of light can travel in one second.

If we presume that the wires are made from perfect superconducting material and have no losses in themselves, how fast will electrical field establish itself at location where our resistor R1 is (be at 5V).

Would current flow unobstructed the whole length with the same current strength until it reaches the R1 resistor and would it only at that time "reduce" itself to 50mA when it is impeded by R1 resistance?

Comment: Add a simple switch into the circuit at one end.  Closing this switch will show the interaction of the electric and magnetic fields as it travels towards the resistor at the speed of light.  Google [poynting-vector](https://www.google.co.za/webhp#q=poynting-vector) for more information.  In very simple terms this vector presents the spatial power product between the electrical field and the magnetic field, in the same way the normal power is the product between the voltage and the current.

Comment: Your circuit would also involve inductance and capacitance distributed along the length of the two conductors so you would need to view this as a (long) transmission wire problem with a termination resistance of 50 ohms. As for speed in the conductors its probably going to be about 0.6 to 0.8c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are imagining a 'transmission line'.

Put a switch in series with your voltage source. When you close it, a wave of 5v and some current will progress along the lines at the speed of light (assuming bare wires in a vacuum, slower if there's air or plastic around).

The impedance of the lines is determined by their geometry. The impedance defines how big the current wave is that progresses along with the voltage wave. If the two lines are fairly close together, say 1mm conductors 10mm apart, the impedance will be about 300ohms, something like the old style FM balanced feeder line. If each wire has thin insulation and they're twisted together, then the impedance will be somewhat lower, 50 to 100 ohm range.

What happens when that wave eventually reaches the 100ohm resistor depends on the line impedance. If they're equal, then the current and the voltage waves will be in just the right ratio to be correct for the resistor as well, and the wave will be totally absorbed, leaving a voltage of 5v on the resistor, with the right current through it.

If they don't match, then a smaller wave will be reflected, to take up the portions of the wave that don't match. The wave will continue to bounce between voltage source and load, until eventually the reflection losses attenuate the waves to insignificance, leaving only the DC flowing between source and resistor.

Comment: Quite a good explanation.  The voltage wave will travel to the resistor.  The current wave will travel back to the source. There will also be a voltage wave travelling back if the impedances are not matched. See [this MIT lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_007S11_lec20.pdf) for a good explanation of how these  electromegnetic waves can also propagate without wires.

Comment: To see an application that uses the current travelling wave see this short summary for power system [fault location.](https://selinc.com/solutions/p/traveling-wave-fault-location/)  (I do not work for SEL.)

Comment: @User1831847 A voltage and current wave travel source to resistor. If it's mismatched, a voltage and current wave get reflected. They go hand in glove, one cannot exist without the other, together they make the Poynting vector, change of mag field makes electric field, movemtnet of electric field makes mag field. Please make sure you don't answer any questions with your separation of waves view, the topic is complicated enough as it is, please don't spread misinformation.

Comment: I differ, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflections_of_signals_on_conducting_lines) clearly states: "The incident wave travelling down the line is not affected in any way by the open circuit (or resistor) at the end of the line. It cannot have any effect until the step actually reaches that point. The signal cannot have any foreknowledge of what is at the end of the line and is only affected by the local characteristics of the line."

Comment: @user1831847 I completely agree with you, wikipedia is correct. Perhaps we disagree about something else? Once it's hit the end of the line, it's no longer an incident wave, consisting of voltage and current together, but voltage and current across whatever load, and a reflected voltage and current wave.

Comment: Yes, the load current is a wave travelling back from the ideal resistor.  With it travels the voltage drop.  It will take approximately two times the length divided by the speed of light for the load current to reach the load.  Only when the load current reaches the load will load power start to travel towards the load.

Comment: @user1831847 No. A current, determined by the line impedance, travels out with the voltage wave. If the line is matched, then the wave is absorbed in the load. If the line is mismatched, then the reflected wave handles the differences. Eg a 50 ohm line with 5v source, 100mA current wave and 5v voltage wave incident. Assume 100ohm load. Load takes 66.7mA at 6.67V. Reflected wave of +1.67v and -33mA (as it's travelling away) add voltage and reduce current at the load, and reduce the net current on the line to 67mA as it travels back. Source supplies 100mA until wave gets back. 1.67/33m =  50 ohm

Comment: In real life, large power transmission lines, the open circuit currents are in the order 10 A to 100 A and the short circuit current 10 kA to 20 kA.  I am not sure what the characteristic impedance $$Z_0$$ is.

Comment: @user1831847 Now I see the problem, we're talking about different types of transmission line! With 5v and 100ohms in the OP, the OP is clearly talking about the same type I'm talking about, which is RF transmission lines, which operate in TEM mode (Transverse Electric Magnetic), and have a well defined characteristic impedance that controls size of voltage and current waves. Power transmission lines operate at such a low frequency, they are usually considered wires, matching is irrelevant, waves are attenuated so fast to be irrelevant, though delay effects are seen for continent-wide ones.

Comment: @user1831847 In real life, a 100ohm load on a 50ohm line is pretty much the 'reflection 101' of any electronics course.

Comment: @user1831847 I've just read the wikipedia page on reflection you linked to. Go down to the section 'arbitrary impedance', which does in algebra what I did with numbers for the 50ohm line 100 ohm load calculations above.

Answer (score 2):

When the voltage source is switched on, an electric field is created, coming from the battery. This electric field would travel at the speed of light. As the 'very-long' wires are superconducting, the electrons have no resistance, and when acted on by the electric field, they would *accelerate*. This happens as the electric field is a force, and that causes the electrons, having some mass, to accelerate (quantum effects notwithstanding). An electric field accelerates electrons in free space. There is no notion of a single current to define the electron motion. Instead the current would rise and would be different at different points in the wire. Why this is so is because current is defined as

I=qnAv

where I is the current, v is the velocity of the electrons as a whole (called drift velocity), q is the electronic charge unit and A is the wire cross sectional area.

This electric field (traveling at the speed of light), and the accelerating electrons (traveling at near the speed of light as they have mass and take time to speed up) would then, after 10 seconds, hit the resistive element. Here the electric field continues to travel at c(speed of light), but now the electrons in the resistor only speed up to a velocity defined by the conductor, because now the electrons face resistance to movement from the resistor atoms.

The accelerating electrons from the superconducting wire, would also hit the resistor a bit later after the field, and they too would slow down, reaching the velocity of electrons already in the resistor. This hitting and slowing down, (and many other transient effects that I am not able to go deeper into), would continue and reduce until the motion of the electrons (as a whole) reach steady state and cause a measurable constant DC current of, as you said, 50 mA.

Comment: Electron drift velocity is nowhere near the speed of light.

Comment: @pjc50, Obviously, but I was mentioning the motion of electrons as a whole, or as a sort of fluid so to speak

Comment: @TransistorOverlord What would be the scenario with electrons if the resistance element was 1ohm (being lower then the characteristic impedance)? In that case the resistor would represent "wider channel" for electron flow, right?

Comment: @StjepanV If the wires from the battery to the R1 resistor (1 ohm now) are superconducting, then the same phenomena happens. However this time the steady state current will be 5 A. If the wires have some impedance, then effects such as standing waves would be seen as others have told.

Comment: @StjepanV The lower resistance of 1 ohm will represent a "wider channel", but it is still a resistance to electron flow, just lesser this time.

Answer (score 2):

If you've ever bought some coax you will have noticed that it generally comes in 50 ohm and 75 ohm varieties. This doesn't mean that you can measure 50 ohm with a meter; what it means is that the coax is physically dimensioned so that if 1 volt were applied, the intial current would be 20 mA. In fact, if the coax was infinitely long, with 1 volt applied, 20 mA would continue to flow.

So there is a power of 20 mW flowing down the cable and when it "hits" the load, if the resistance of the load isn't 50 ohm then some of that power is reflected back up the wire; you get a wave-front travelling down and a wave-front travelling back. If you send a pulse down your cable and it meets another cable of different impedance this happens: -

[image]

Some energy continues and some is reflected back to the source. This can play havoc with data comms. If you send a pulse down and it sees a short circuit all the signal is returned but inverted: -

[image]

Pretty pictures taken from [here](http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/reflect/reflect.html) and note that this website is about physical reflections in a mechanical system and of course, the maths is pretty much the same and to emphasize that here is a pulse travelling down to hit what is in effect an open circuit: -

[image]

The bottom line is that if the impedance of the medium matches the load then power is transferred with no reflection. Here's an interesting scenario; a sinewave is sent down a cable and hits a short circuit: -

[image]

Notice how the travelling waves from left to right and back from right to left combine to produce a stationary wave (called a standing wave). The ratio of the peaks to the nulls is the standing wave ratio and in this lossless example the SWR is infinite. In practise, cable losses reduce the SWR but a short circuit can produce SWRs of tens or hundreds. A perfect match has an SWR of 1.

Comment: your last picture shows nicely how the voltage reaches the resistor and the current wave travels back, with the reflected voltage wave.

Comment: @user1831847 no, that's not quite what is indicated. Voltage travels down and a voltage is reflected back. Because the reflected voltage sees (say) 50 ohm then reflected current is in phase with voltage. Basically power travels back in the reflection but there's no point showing both v and I on the diagram.